# Custom control rendering twice

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am extending sap.ui.unified.Calendar with a custom control, overriding the renderDays() function, to place an extra span tag in each day div.

The console indicates the hours array is undefined. It throws the error found below, but continues to work afterwards. This error prevents using the header arrows to move between months in the calendar. Is this rendering twice? Why is hours[] undefined at first but ok after?

If I put all the code into a single file JSBin, it does not error.
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/setowekuko/1/edit?html,console,output)

The top of the code for the custom control:

```
sap.ui.unified.Calendar.extend("control.TimeCalendar", {
    metadata : {
        properties : {
            "hoursData" : "string[]"
        }
    },

  renderer: {
    renderDays: function(oRm, oCal, oDate){
        var hours = oCal.getHoursData();
```

Console output:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Excerpt from the custom control TimeCalender.js. This is inside the do...while loop which places each day on the calendar. Where the function places the date, I also include a span tag with a number retrieved from the array 'hours'.

```
oRm.write("<span class=\"sapUiCalDayNum\">");

if ( (hours.length>i) && (hours[i].day == oDay.getUTCDate()) ) {
    oRm.write("<span class=\"hours\">");
    oRm.write(hours[i].hours);
    oRm.write("</span>");
    if(i <= hours.length) { i++; }
}

oRm.write(oDay.getUTCDate());
oRm.write("</span>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess, I would say that in your non-jsbin scenario you are using databinding and the data is either received asynchonously from the back-end or it is set after the first rendering?

In that case the hoursdata value is set to undefined, which causes the error.

If you define the property like this:

```
properties : {
    "hoursData" : { type: "string[]", defaultValue: [] }
}
```

...this way you make sure that there is always an array, which has a length property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe the problem was with it loading asynchronously, as you said. When I changed the model in the controller to read from a variable I defined in the same file, instead of pointing to the url of a json file, it worked. So I changed the controller to use loadData and set the async flag to false, and that fixed the problem. I later changed to an OData service which also had async to false, and it worked, too.

Comment: Synchronous loading is the wrong way to do it in almost every case - it blocks the UI thread and often leads to poor user experience. You should use the default value and think about some logic inside your renderer - for example abort when no data is set so you can use async loading when it is needed.

Comment: I understand it's a bad idea to load it synchronously. However I still get the undefined error when changing my OData call to be asynchronous even with your defaultValue: [] suggestion. I have used typeof to determine the type of getHoursData() and it is an object, not undefined which I did not expect.

Comment: You can still check for undefined before the error happens: "if (!oControl.getHoursData()) return;"